# Is using std::future the best way to safely stop a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm reading [this](https://thispointer.com/c11-how-to-stop-or-terminate-a-thread/) tutorial on how to safely exit from threads.

In essence, it passes a future object to the function that is going to be executed from the thread, and checks, at every while loop, if that future already has a value (if it has, it exits the thread). See:

```
void threadFunction(std::future<void> futureObj)
{
    std::cout << "Thread Start" << std::endl;
    while (futureObj.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) == std::future_status::timeout)
    {
        std::cout << "Doing Some Work" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    }
    std::cout << "Thread End" << std::endl;

}
```

The problem is that in order to check if `futureObj` is already setted, it has to wait for some time (here, 1 millissecond). So, I'm losing 1 millissecond on every iteration of the thread. Shouldn't this be preferable:

```
void threadFunction(bool *shouldStop)
{
    std::cout << "Thread Start" << std::endl;
    while (!*shouldStop)
    {
        std::cout << "Doing Some Work" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    }
    std::cout << "Thread End" << std::endl;

}
```

In order to check `shouldStop`, no time is wasted. So my thread runs faster. Why he didn't do that?

**UPDATE:**
Here's a simple class that should do the same thing, I guess.

```
class Stoppable
{
private:
    std::atomic<bool> _shouldContinue;

public:
    Stoppable()
    {
        _shouldContinue.store(true);
    }

    virtual void run() = 0;
    void operator()()
    {
        run();
    }
    bool shouldContinue()
    {
        return _shouldContinue.load();
    }
    void stop()
    {
        _shouldContinue.store(false);
    }
};
```

Then, to use it, just subclass `Stoppable` and do like this:

```
void MySubClass::run()
{
    while (shouldContinue())
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are confused between the task of stopping a thread, and checking whether a thread is stopped. There's nothing that a `std::future` can do in order to "stop a thread". All that `std::future` does is indicate to you whether the thread has stopped. If you want to wait until the thread is finished, that's what `join()` is for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think you may want to read the code again. The thread being stopped holds the future, and the thread(s) doing the stopping is the one holding the promise. The thread being stopped checks the future and terminates when it's full.

Comment: You can apply `wait_for` with 0 milliseconds. There are indeed other methods to achieve the same result (not with `bool` though, atomic bool would work). The only main difference is that the `std::future<T>` can be used to pass variable can be waited upon if needed, and IIRC it indicates that the event happens only once. This case is but an example of how `std::future<T>` can be used. Though, honestly in most cases I found `std::condition_variable` to be better utility.

Comment: You might still wind up waiting for the better part of a millisecond. Use a `std::condition_variable` with a timeout so you can kick the thread awake early

Comment: `std::atomic<bool>` seems the rigth way to do it. There's no reason to wait, even if just a millissecond. Why no one uses it?

Comment: When one writes an article one needs examples. Sometimes (I'd say often) examples are contrived and uses suboptimal solutions just to show some concept or instruction/function. You do not need a future/promise pair as a one way method of notifying a thread that it has to stop.

Comment: Reasoning behind the sleep: there may be no need to do work constantly, and doing so may result in a tight loop sucking up to 100% of a processor core for no good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second proposal:

`void threadFunction(bool *shouldStop)`

Is I am afraid wrong if you intend to set `*shouldStop` from another thread.

In this case it should be `void threadFunction(std::atomic<bool> *shouldStop)`.

There is no one "right way" to signal a thread to stop as it will depend on whether you want your thread to work continually or only work when there is work to do. But there are wrong ways - usually involving undefined behaviour because of writing to a non-atomic variable in one thread and reading from it in another.

If you want your thread to continually work until stopped (for example, this is common in graphics rendering threads or real-time game logic threads) then there is no reason to wait before checking your stop signal.

If your thread is a worker thread which will only run while there is work to do, then it's more normal to use a `std::condition_variable`, `std::mutex` and a queue plus a signal.

In case it's interesting, here's an example of an implementation of a work queue. Note that this one permits completion of the work out of order with respect to submission. There are many strategies available:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


struct worker_control
{
    std::queue<std::function<void()>> work_queue;
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool stop_signal = false;

    void post_work(std::function<void()> f)
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(m);
        work_queue.push(std::move(f));
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void request_stop()
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(m);
        stop_signal = true;
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_all();
    }
};

std::mutex emit_mutex;
template<class...Args>
void emit(Args&&...args)
{
    auto lock = std::unique_lock(emit_mutex);

    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " : ";

    ((std::cout << args), ...);

    std::cout << '\n';
}

void run_worker(worker_control& control)
{

    auto should_run = [&]
    {
        return not control.work_queue.empty() or control.stop_signal;
    };

    while (1)
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(control.m);

        control.cv.wait(lock, should_run);

        // at this point we own the lock on control.m

        if (not control.work_queue.empty())
        {
            auto work = std::move(control.work_queue.front());
            control.work_queue.pop();
            lock.unlock(); // allow other workers access to the queue
            work();
        }
        else
        {
            // we can only have got here if there is no work to do and we have been asked to stop
            return;
        }
    }
}



int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> worker_threads;

    auto control = worker_control();

    worker_threads.emplace_back([&]{ run_worker(control); });
    worker_threads.emplace_back([&]{ run_worker(control); });
    worker_threads.emplace_back([&]{ run_worker(control); });

    control.post_work([]{ emit("the"); });
    control.post_work([]{ emit("quick"); });
    control.post_work([]{ emit("brown"); });
    control.post_work([]{ emit("fox"); });
    control.post_work([]{ emit("jumps"); });
    control.post_work([]{ emit("over"); });
    control.post_work([]{ emit("the"); });
    control.post_work([]{ emit("lazy"); });
    control.post_work([]{ emit("dog"); });

    control.request_stop();

    for (auto& t : worker_threads)
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();

}
```

Example output:

```
140244960823040 : the
140244960823040 : fox
140244960823040 : jumps
140244960823040 : over
140244960823040 : the
140244960823040 : lazy
140244960823040 : dog
140244969215744 : quick
140244952430336 : brown
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1612695a3cfc955

Comment: Thank you, I did as you said (using std::atomic<bool>), but I made a class that can be subclassed. Can you look at my update? I think it's ok.